# Non Decimal Numbers on Math.ceil or Math.round in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, rounding

I want to use Javascript to round up a number. 
For example like this,

```
15 => 20
345 => 400
201 => 300
180 => 200
93 => 100
22 => 30
```

How to achieve this using Javascript? I know i can use Math.ceil or Math.round but this is not decimal numbers.

Comment: I'd suggest you revert your edit, because you've already got good answers to the original question.

Comment: I consider it rather rude that you edit your question in such a way that a formerly correct answer will now become incorrect.

Comment: I'm So Sorry..I'm just reedit again my question right away...

Answer (score 2):

Solution for your first example:

```
var n = 15;
n /= 10; //n = 1.5
n = Math.ceil(n); //n = 2
n *= 10; //n = 20
```

The other examples work the same way.

Answer (score 2):

To round to the nearest multiple of 100, you can write

```
100*Math.ceil(x/100)
```

Similarly for other factors.

Choosing a “nice” factor might be a different problem. You could take the base-10 logarithm of your numbers, multiply that by three and round. Then you could apply the following map:

```
3*round(log10(x))  factor
               0    1
               1    2
               2    5
               3   10
               4   20
               5   50
```

You don't have to store that table: using modulo operations, you can compute the leading digit of the factor, and using the floor of the third part you get the number of trailing zeros.

Whether this is appropriate depends on your application. The code in your question appears to only use factors which are a power of 10. In that case, don't do the multiplication by 3 in the above approach, but instead simply use the floor of the base 10 log directly:

```
factor = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(x)/Math.log(10)));
rounded = Math.ceil(x/factor)*factor;
```

Comment: What makes a good programmer is the ability to understand fuzzy specifications. ;)

Comment: Works on example input from original question: http://ideone.com/Meb868. However, the question was edited since, so the answer no longer applies as is.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you want depends on the precision.

A basic solution would be

```
function round(num, precision) { 
  var div = Math.pow(10, precision); 
  return Math.ceil(num/div)*div;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about you divide your numbers by 10/100/1000 to have decimals, then ceil/round. Then multiply again.

This is the first solution that comes to my mind.